# Method to solve solar heat transfer equation

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Solar radiation heat transfer between two surfaces is a fairly common problem for solar physics. The equations vary; but usually include the solar energy flux and thermal radiation from a surface described with the Stefan-Boltzmann equation. This is : phi= sigma*T^4.  For two surfaces and a source, you get an equation like this:  Total flux (watts/meter^2) (time,Temp_surface1, Temp_surface2)=  solar flux+ sigma*(temp_surface1)^4 + sigma*(temp_surface2)^4. 
    This is a quartic equation with three variables. The examples I have seen hold time constant over an hour (e.g. Noon-1p.m.)  and find solar flux from a table.
That leaves the two surface temperatures (e.g. a metal absorbing plate and cover in a solar water heater) as unknowns. The Total flux becomes a function of the temperature of the two surfaces and the resultant IR radiation from the two surfaces.
  What is the best approach to analyze a system like this? I want to find a relation or relations between the two temperatures and then verify it by experiment using an IR meter (Extech).

Comment: A good text is Solar Engineering of Thermal Processes by Duffie and Beckman

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have the 1973 edition and the 2013 edition. I'm trying to find a workable formula. Tried the ones on p.129 which suggest ~ an educated guess on the cover temperature and then refine the figures. That's sort of what I've been doing. I may be getting to something. I'm studying plastic covers and have some formulas from an article on solar air heaters.  Link is  ...http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.474.3665&rep=rep1&type=pdf